# Xamarin.Forms: Creating a Chart

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms

Good Day. I'm just a newbie in using simple Xamarin.Forms (Portable). I'm creating a simple Application and I want to display there a Chart ( **Bar Graph, Line Graph, Pie Chart,** etc ). Can anyone help me create one? Thanks a lot.

Comment: be more specific, if possible with a code example

Comment: @DirkHorsten I don't have a code for chart yet Sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a library that will help you display charts have a look at OxyPlot. It is free and gives you quite a few charting types. You can add it to your projects as [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/) package. For documentation on how to get started there is an official documentation [here](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/index.html). With a dedicated section to [Xamarin.Forms](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html).

**Edit January 2018:**
In the last couple of months a new library has been on the highrise in the Xamarin community. If you are looking for a free charting lib, be sure to check out [Microcharts](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts).

Comment: Thanks Sir. But I have a problem, it oxyplot doesn't appear in my Nuget Packages for Solution. Only "oxyplot-extensions", "Eto.OxyPlot.wpf",  and "Eto.OxyPlot" appears whenever I search for OXYPLOT. Is there a specific package I can just Install in Package Manager Console?

Comment: Hey @JayceeEvangelista try selecting "Include prerelease" and you will see more packages. Be sure to include the Core, Forms, Android etc. package. Currently there is no stable version of OxyPlot for Xamarin - I have used it myself and it seems to do a fair job.

Comment: OxyPlot seems like it's gone stale, but upvoted for the update to the answer about Microcharts.